# One time Password in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, one-time-password

I want to use OTP for my node-express API.
Right now I am able to personalize things using username and password, but would like to do it using mobile number and OTP.
What references can I use for this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to just verify the phone by sending and OTP and then asking for it then I don't think you should go for Speakeasy.

Speakeasy is mainly for TOTP and HOTP which are more like 2 Factor Authentication (generate OTPs every 30 seconds, for example).

But since you want to verify a user's phone once all you need to do is:

1. Generate any random n-digit number and save it in a table in DB mapped to user with creation time.
2. Send this to the user's phone. You can use any service. I personally use twilio.
3. When user enters the OTP, check the current time against the creation time and see if it's valid.
4. Handle the cases: a) if valid: mark user as verified
                    b) if invalid: whatever you want to do.

Comment: I also want my application to remember the current user and changes the view accordingly. While using passport-authentication, it returns some "x-access-token" through which we can personalize the app for the particular customer. Does this otplib also returns any such thing?
If not, how can i remember the present user?

Answer (score 5):

*See here you have to do it like this*:

**Workflow**:

1. use Message sending Api like `twilio`, `OpenTok` something like that.
2. use `Socket.io` for real time interaction while sending messages
3. `speakeasy` npm package you should use as it makes very to generate one time password code
4. Use `express` to create your application

**Reference**:

[OTP Verification using NODE & EXPRESS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/verify-phone-numbers-with-node-js-using-twilio-sms-express-and-socket-io.html)

**Git Repo**:

[Download Working Code](https://github.com/jonmarkgo/TwilioNodePhoneVerification.git)

Comment: Speakeasy is mainly for TOTP and HOTP which are more like 2 Factor Authentication (generate OTPs every 30 seconds, for example). But it's overkill for phone verification